# Retorno array Json Mysql

Tags: mysql, json

Tenho duas tabelas dentro em um banco de dados, e preciso que retorne os dados em uma array

Hoje tenho o retorno somente da tabela **tbl_categorias_fotos**

O retorno e assim.

```js
    [
    {
        "id_cat_fotos": "3",
        "nome_cat_fotos": "Transformador Principal",
        "desc_nome_cat_fotos": "O transformador principal e o componente que recebe a tensão da distribuidora"
    },
    {
        "id_cat_fotos": "4",
        "nome_cat_fotos": "Transformador Secundário",
        "desc_nome_cat_fotos": "O Transformador principal e o componente que recebe a tensão do transformador Principal"
    },
    {
        "id_cat_fotos": "5",
        "nome_cat_fotos": "Titulo",
        "desc_nome_cat_fotos": "Descrição Teste 00",
    }
    ]
```

Estou tentando puxar os dados da tabela **tbl_fotos_empresa** que são referentes a um determinado usuário

```
    [
{
    "id_cat_fotos": "3",
    "nome_cat_fotos": "Transformador Principal",
    "desc_nome_cat_fotos": "O transformador principal e o componente que recebe a tensão da distribuidora",
    "fotos": {
        "nome_foto_empresa": "Nome da foto",
        "descri_foto_empresa": "Descricao"
    }
},
{
    "id_cat_fotos": "4",
    "nome_cat_fotos": "Transformador Secundário",
    "desc_nome_cat_fotos": "O Transformador principal e o componente que recebe a tensão do transformador Principal"
},
{
    "id_cat_fotos": "5",
    "nome_cat_fotos": "Titulo",
    "desc_nome_cat_fotos": "Descrição Teste 00",
    "fotos": {
        "nome_foto_empresa": "xIIv52hz_1557963798.jpg",
        "descri_foto_empresa": "Descricao"
    },
    "fotos": {
        "nome_foto_empresa": "lCq3QcRF_1557967320.jpg",
        "descri_foto_empresa": "Descricao"
    },
    "fotos": {
        "nome_foto_empresa": "lCq3QcRF_1557967388.jpg",
        "descri_foto_empresa": "Descricao"
    }
}
]
```

Sera que consigo concatenar o mesmo SQL e exibir como o exemplo acima?
Alguem pode me dar uma dica de como buscar e exibir

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  tbl_categorias_fotos";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $array[] = array(
            'id_cat_fotos' => $row["id_cat_fotos"], 
            'nome_cat_fotos' => $row["nome_cat_fotos"], 
            'desc_nome_cat_fotos' => $row["desc_nome_cat_fotos"]
    );

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Se você tiver só uma foto por categoria, você poderia fazer uma select único:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM  tbl_categorias_fotos cat LEFT JOIN tbl_fotos_empresa fotos ON cat.id_cat_fotos = fotos.id_cat_fotos";
```

Utilizei o LEFT JOIN para caso alguma categoria não tenha foto mesmo assim ele retornar;

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $array[] = array(
        'id_cat_fotos' => $row["id_cat_fotos"], 
        'nome_cat_fotos' => $row["nome_cat_fotos"], 
        'desc_nome_cat_fotos' => $row["desc_nome_cat_fotos"],
        'fotos' => array(
                      'nome_foto_empresa' => $row["nome_foto_empresa"],
                      'descri_foto_empresa' => $row["descri_foto_empresa"]
        )
    );
}
```

Acredito que desta maneira você irá conseguir a saída que você quer, depois é só converter em json, utilizando json_encode();

Por favor, faça os ajustes quanto as colunas do seu banco. Espero ter passado a ideia.

Comment: montei aqui, mas vc acha que teria como se uma categoria possuísse mais de uma foto, ela seja exibida na mesma array de fotos?

Comment: Talvez nessa situação você teria que fazer alguma tratativa, tal como. trazer tudo ou seja tuplas repetidas, porém dispensar a parte repetida e ir incluindo só as fotos. ou para cada interação das categorias você fazer uma consulta passando o id da categoria para foto especifica de cada categoria. porém isso iria consumir muito recurso dependendo da quantidade de categorias. deu para entender?

Comment: Sim entendi, e cheguei nesta mesma conclusão, terá muito mais consumo que o necessário, estou vendo com o DEV do APP se podemos incluir estas fotos apos o clique na categoria, que creio que sera muito mais viável

Comment: Sim! Existe um tecnologia chamada Ajax, que você pode tornar tais chamadas muito mais versáteis e rápidas. Desta maneira suas fotos seriam carregadas por demanda. Você poderia fazer o seguinte utilizar este select da resposta para trazer somente uma foto e quando o cliente clicasse sobre a categoria carregar as outras através do Ajax.

Comment: Espero ter ajudado. Qualquer duvida é só falar. Se a resposta tiver lhe ajudado não esqueça de qualifica-la .